# How do I write a command to run as administrator?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I write a bat file to run as administrator and then be able to have the credentials automatically entered in.

For example if it was user:LocalAdmin and password:password. I currently have the run as admin as

runas.exe /savecred /user:LocalAdmin "C:\Users\LocalAdmin\Desktop\test.bat"

But once I run this it asks me for a password. Is there a way to put the password in there so it does not ask for the password

Answer (score 0):

In looking at the help for /SAVECRED it may be possible to run it once with manually entering the credentials, and then the next run will used the saved credentials.

If that doesn't work, look at a way to use Impersonation from a scripting language (VBScript or PowerShell for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt, the answer is no. See the following blog post for the reasons:

[FAQ: Why can't I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/faq-why-can-8217-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/ba-p/701510)

Relevant excerpts from that FAQ:

> The designers of Windows Vista's User Account Control expressly decided not to incorporate functionality like setuid/suid or sudo found in Unix and Unix-like OSes such as Mac OS X. I think they made the right decision.
>
> ...
>
> If it were possible to mark an application to run with silently-elevated privileges, what would become of all those apps out there with LUA bugs? Answer: they'd all be marked to silently elevate. How would future software for Windows be written? Answer: To silently elevate. Nobody would actually fix their apps, and end-user applications will continue to require and run with full administrative permissions unnecessarily.